# Variadic Template for qobject_cast via parent()

Tags: c++, qt, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

gurus and template-experts, I need your help ...

I am currently looking for a solution on checking a QObject's parent hierarchy. I have a custom QDialog with the following hierarchy (parent to child):

```
QDockWidget
> CustomDockArea
  > QMainWindow
    > QDockWidget
      > CustomDialog
```

Within the CustomDialog class, I want to check if the dialog's hierarchy matches this example, so I checked if this is accomplishable with a variadic template, for example:

```
assert(qobject_cast_parent<QDockWidget*, QMainWindow*, CustomDockArea*, QDockWidget*>(this));
```

and I have come up with something like this:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
inline T qobject_cast_parent(QObject* root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        if (sizeof...(Ts) == 0)
        {
            return qobject_cast<T>(root->parent());
        }
        else
        {
            return qobject_cast_parent<Ts...>(root->parent());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

However, there a few problems: I need the last parameter of the parameter pack as being the return type of the function, in our example QDockWidget*. I could take the first parameter as being the return type, but this would make the template call a little bit cumbersome. However, even if that would be solved, I think there is still a problem with the way the parameter pack is "unrolled" and now I got a little bit unsure if my template-approach is even feasible for the original problem. Maybe you can give me some hints. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: "I want to check if the hierarchy is correct." Why does `CustomDialog` care about the entire hierarchy tree? It's a dialog, it's supposed to be usable on its own without a parent... Sure, it can *add* to its functionality if it has the right parents going towards the root of the tree, but you shouldn't care exactly where these parents are. You can simply use the first and second `QDockWidget` you find going up the hierarchy, but even then I think such an interface is clunky. Perhaps you should expose a couple signals/slots instead and offer a helper method that hooks them up to a certain tree.

Comment: The word "correct" might be misleading, I edited my answer accordingly. The dialog's behavior is dependent on it's position within the hierarchy and therefore certain checks are necessary.

Comment: Perhaps the dialog should be explicitly told what to do, from the code that is aware of the hierarchy? That would be much cleaner. As it is, you're exposing an API to your dialog that is not expressed in terms of the class's signature...

Answer (score 2):

With c++14, you may simply use `auto` as return type:

```
template <class T>
T* qobject_cast_parent(QObject* root)
{
    return root
        ? qobject_cast<T*>(root->parent())
        : nullptr;
}

template <class T, class T2, class... Ts>
auto qobject_cast_parent(QObject* root)
//-> typename Last<T2, Ts...>::type /* In c++11, you have to create this traits */
{
    return root
        ? qobject_cast_parent<T2, Ts...>(qobject_cast<T*>(root->parent()))
        : nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have your complete code, I can only confirm that the following compiles, but could not test it.  I'm sure you can test it for me though, let me know if this doesn't work or if I misunderstood your problem.

```
#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

// This ends the recursion with the actual qobject_cast.
template <class T, class U>
inline U *qobject_cast_parent(T* root)
{
  // Make sure everything's a QObject, clear message if not.
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value, "Object must be a QObject");

  if (root)
  {
    return qobject_cast<U *>(root->parent());
  }
  else
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
}

template <class T, class U, class... Us>
inline U *qobject_cast_parent(T* root)
{
  // Make sure everything's a QObject, clear message if not.
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value, "Object must be a QObject");

  if (root)
  {
    return qobject_cast_parent<U, Us...>(qobject_cast<U *>(root->parent()))
  }
  else
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

So the template parameters are ordered from child to parent, and you'll be forced to specify the innermost type as well.  So I think your `assert` example would look like this (again, untested, let me know how it works out):

```
assert(qobject_cast_parent<CustomDialog,
                           QDockWidget,
                           QMainWindow,
                           CustomDockArea,
                           QDockWidget>(this));
```

**Edit**: For sake of completeness, you were also asking about a way to get to the type of last parameter of a parameter pack.  You could use something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Last
{
  typedef typename Last<Ts...>::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Last<T>
{
  typedef T type;
};

int main()
{
  // For example, this gives std::string:
  Last<int, float, char, std::string>::type foo = "bar";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! It is not quite working yet, I get "cannot convert argument 1 from 'CustomDialog *' to 'QDockWidget *' with [ U=QMainWindow T=QDockWidget ]" ... However, this template ending the recursion is helpful for my solution, so I think I am actually quite close, I am also having a solution for getting the last argument from the parameter pack and returning it.

Comment: @ChrisInked Oops, I think I found the problem.  It should be `qobject_cast<U*> in the second function; updated my answer. Does that fix it?